# Uncaught TypeError: t.resolve is not a function ... polyfills

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, heroku

I deployed angular application to heroku, locally is working well but in cloud I received an error: Uncaught TypeError: t.resolve is not a function

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.resolve is not a function
    at Object.setNativePromise (polyfills.d6224da1db9162756f6d.bundle.js:1)
    at L.configurable.L.set (polyfills.d6224da1db9162756f6d.bundle.js:1)
    at e.exports (dz.js:1)
    at e (dz.js:1)
    at Object../node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js (dz.js:1)
    at t (dz.js:1)
    at Object../js/_bundles/dz/dz.js (dz.js:1)
    at t (dz.js:1)
    at ./images/common/cover_500x500.jpg (dz.js:1)
    at dz.js:1
```

Anyone any ideea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described. Without code, its almost impossible to guess what went wrong.